# Matlab make matrix from calculation

Tags: matlab, matrix, output

so i have this code, 
        clc
        data=[1;3;4;3;5;2;5]
        cnt=size(data,1)

```
    for i=2:cnt;
        im=(data(i)-(data(i-1)))    
    end
    im
```

i need a matrix output from that code

but my output still like this

```
data =

     1
     3
     4
     3
     5
     2
     5


cnt =

     7


im =

     2


im =

     1


im =

    -1


im =

     2


im =

    -3


im =

     3
```

how to make this kind of output?

```
im =

     2
     1
    -1
     2
    -3
     3
```

i still confused to got an output like that?

Comment: Try this: diff(data)

Comment: sorry i shoul add that im trying not usung diff function :)

Comment: Then try this: im=data(2:end)-data(1:end-1)

Comment: Why are you trying to not use the `diff` function? This is its exact purpose and it is inbuilt...

Comment: just currious how to get the same ouutput as diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the for loop, you could do:

```
cnt=size(data,1);
im = zeros(cnt-1,1); % create empty diff array
for i=2:cnt
    im(i-1)=(data(i)-(data(i-1))) % fill it 
end
```